# ElasticSearch query doesn't work

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following document:

```
{
        "_index": "taskmanager",
        "_type": "tasks",
        "_id": "AVn4vhIKiS68kYrc2Xp0",
        "_score": 0.8784157,
        "_source": {
          "Id": 2,
          "Title": "Hello World",
          "Description": "Description example",
          "PublishDate": "2017-01-29T15:06:04",
          "IsCompleted": true
        }
```

I can got the list of documents executing the query:

```
var hits = elasticClient.Search<Task>(s => s);
```

But I got nothing trying to get documents which contains 'world'.

```
var hits = elasticClient.Search<DalTask>(s => s
                .Type("tasks")
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                        .Field(p => p.Title).Query("world")
                    )
                )
            ).Hits;
```

Where is my mistake? 
P.s. My index set to default "taskmanager".

Comment: seems to be fine. Can you debug this and share what is the query that is created. You can do a quick view of the 'hits' object to get the query.

Comment: can you share your schema and settings for your index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NEST camel cases C# POCO property names when serializing them to Elasticsearch document field names in the request, so

```
.Field(p => p.Title)
```

becomes

```
"title"
```

in the request. Looking at the `_source` in the response you have posted, it looks like your field names are Pascal-cased, hence the casing of field name in the search request is different and will not match.

You can change how NEST serializes C# POCO property names by changing `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(Func<string, string>)` on `ConnectionSettings`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    // serialize POCO property names verbatim
    .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```